# How do I implement Admin SDK in my flutter so that I should Manage the users from Admin Panel?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, admin, google-admin-sdk

I'm new to flutter working on my Final Year Project. I want to implement Admin functionalities in my App. So far I had implemented the data flow and the authentication things but I am stuck at implementing the Admin SDK for the removal of users from the auth table so that the admin has the complete priviligies.

Is there any alternate way possible? Or I have to implement the Admin SDK for this. Kindly guide? And if yes how should I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDKs are designed to be used in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run. They are explicitly not to be used in client-side applications, like your Flutter app.

If you want to create a Flutter app that can be used to manage users, you'll want to:

- Create your own API end points (e.g. with Cloud Functions or Cloud Run) where you use the Admin SDK to implement the necessary use-cases.
- Secure those end points so that only authorized users can call them,
- Then call the API end points from within your Flutter application code.

Also see:

- [How to use Firebase Admin SDK in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290458/how-to-use-firebase-admin-sdk-in-flutter)
- [is it possible to use firebase admin SDK in flutter web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939723/is-it-possible-to-use-firebase-admin-sdk-in-flutter-web-apps)
- [Flutter - Understanding Firebase Admin and how to get a user's information from email/uid/name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63548004/flutter-understanding-firebase-admin-and-how-to-get-a-users-information-from)